# Changing a user's home directory to a specific folder inside root

Tags: permissions, home-directory

I'm in a predicament where I need to set a user: ftpuser (that does not have sudo access) to it's home directory and not do anything else apart from be in that directory. However this directory is inside the root folder, I cannot move the directory as it needs root to be able to run. Can anyone help me?

I've done:

```
sudo usermod -d /root/fivem ftpuser
```

I've read in the

```
etc/passwd
```

That it is set to /root/fivem however when I join via FTP it puts me in / and not in /root/fivem.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason for what really is a really stupid idea? If you want to do this you create a new directory in root (preferably a mount point).

Answer (score 0):

The default permissions for /root are `rwx------`, so your user can't access his home directory /root/fivem. You must set the permissions of both /root and /root/fivem so that it can be accessed by ftpuser.

(I don't know if that's a good idea, but if you absolutely want to use such a home directory, it is necessary.)

Comment: just add the reading permission at `/root` is necessary to access `/root/fivem`,  and he can add more permission at ``/root/fivem` if he needed it